# Don't allow to dynamically create public properties

Tags: php, oop, php-7

Let's start with simple PHP code:

```
<?php

class Test 
{
}

$test = new Test();
$test->x = 20;
echo $test->x;
```

The problem here is this code works without any problem (tested in PHP 7.1, probably in some previous versions it works also without any problems).

The problem I see here that when using code like this, it's very easy to write code that is very hard to analyse and can contain some hidden bugs.

**The question**: is there any way to don't allow to dynamically create properties for objects especially outside of the class?

For custom class like this the solution that could be used is creating custom `__set` method that will creating not declared properties like this:

```
public function __set($property, $value)
{
    if (!property_exists($this, $property)) {
        throw new Exception("Property {$property} does not exit");

    }
    $this->$property = $value;
}
```

but it obviously doesn't solve problem of protected/private properties - property_exists would return true also for protected and private properties (need to use Reflection for this).

Comment: __set() is run when writing data to inaccessible properties. __get() is utilized for reading data from inaccessible properties.  The magic methods are not substitutes for getters and setters. They just allow you to handle method calls or property access that would otherwise result in an error. As such, there are much more related to error handling. Also note that they are considerably slower than using proper getter and setter or direct method calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
class Test 
{
    protected $name="ss";
    public function __set($property, $value)
    {
        //Checked for undefined properties
        if(!isset(get_object_vars($this)[$property]))
        {
             throw new Exception("Property {$property} does not exit");            
        }
        //Checking for public properties
        $prop = new ReflectionProperty($this, "name");
        if(!$prop->isPublic())
        {
            throw new Exception("Property {$property} does not exit");            
        }
        //Checking for non-existing properties
        if (!property_exists($this, $property)) 
        {
            throw new Exception("Property {$property} does not exit");
        }
        $this->$property = $value;
    }
}

$test = new Test();
$test->x = 20;
echo $test->x;
```

Comment: This was typo only in question and the problem is not about this.

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek `The question: is there any way to don't allow to dynamically create properties for objects especially outside of the class?` You have written this in your question.

Comment: Yes, but this is the code I showed. It does not solve other problems I mentioned and if's quite complex solution for easy problem, isn't it?

Comment: @SahilGulati, the OP is showing something he wants to PREVENT. So of course it's working code, he wants to throw an exception or something when someone tries to set a property on an object that wasn't previously declared. (I think this is called sealed?)

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek I have updated my post. I think reflection can be the option for checking property type and preventing it from getting updated outside the class.